# Как выровнять панель rich?

Tags: python

Я создал панель с помощью rich

```
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich import print

print(Panel.fit("Hello world!"))
```

и мне нужно ее выровнять по центру, я пробывал добавить параметр justify, но вылазит ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\failes\все\scripts\pnla.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(Panel("Hello world!"), justify="center")
TypeError: print() got an unexpected keyword argument 'justify'
```

Как это исправить, и возможно ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось через `align.Align`:

```
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich.align import Align
from rich import print

print(Align(Panel("Hello world!"), align='center'))
```

Вывод:

```
                                                 ╭──────────────╮                                                  
                                                 │ Hello world! │                                                  
                                                 ╰──────────────╯
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы расположить желаемый текст по центру необходимо передать желаемое значения аргументом "title".

```
print(Panel("THIS IS THE TEXT", title='THIS IS THE TITLE'))
```

Для того чтобы поменять положения текста необходимо передать в аргумент 'title_align' желаемое положение (center - по умолчанию, left, right).

Результатом выполнения вышеуказанного кода будет:

```
╭───────────────────────────── THIS IS THE TITLE ──────────────────────────────╮
│ THIS IS THE TEXT                                                             │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Comment: Это заголовок вы так задаёте и выравниваете, а речь про основной текст.